# Angular slow drawing

Tags: angularjs, performance

I've got some nested directives inside ng-repeats, they consist of directive that got ng-repeat.
It renders very ugly.
I want to show the content when its finished drawing.
Ive tried to use directives events things like scope.$last, or timeouts but the problem is these elements are created but the browser havent rendered them yet. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

no wonder, you ran into the same problem as me, it's caused by AngularJS dirt checking, it's a cost you using it, but there is not official solution to it yet, there is link has a temp solution you can use, please check on http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/  hope this helps!